# Android webview to work like native browser

Tags: android, android-webview

I experimenting with WebView in Android and I can't figure out how to make it work like the native browser.

I have an example for this:
Go to deviantART.com in native browser. Press Menu button. At the bottom of the menu there will be a link to disable mobile view and it works as expected. This exact same thing doesn't work in WebView. It simply turns the menu off and that is all, mobil CSS still stays intact.

I need to make users disable deviantART's mobile CSS, so I need the WebView to work like this.

JavaScript and DOMStorage are enabled.

I need the proper code or an workaround, but after hours of searching I didn't find anything that connected to this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to turn off the mobile view you can set the user-agent string on the `WebView` using `setUserAgentString (String ua)`.